# Flutter cubit doesn't change state

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'm studying bloc in Flutter now and faced a problem.

In my test app I fetch weather data and when trying to display it I see no changes and no errors.

The trouble is: I do get the data and can see with print, but when it comes to displaying with BlocBuilder, it seems to not change the state.

This is the link to my repo - https://github.com/PhilippBekher/flutter_weather

The logics for displaying data are in main.dart
The weather data is accessible via the link - https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=%20f148ee51b7cd4e2390e110556221408&q=London&days=1

When trying to print the state inside the file for the cubit, I can't see the emitted state (WeatherFetchLoaded):
The screen below:

Comment: Can you put a print line before the `emit` for you new state to see if it actually emits a new state? If you have states and state changes, you should really use a BloC by the way, Cubits are meant for primitive data.

Comment: @nvoigt Thank you for the advice, I will! 
For educational purposes I've found the first video about fetch with bloc concept and decided to study it over , the data there indeed wasn't so complex.
Anyway when I add the print of state inside cubit, I don't see it console

Comment: Well, I guess you triggered one of your catch blocks then. Add prints there, find out which one and what failed.

Comment: @nvoigt All the time get state "Loading"..

Comment: Yes, that is what happens when you end up in a catch block. Again... debug it, or put print statements inside your catch blocks to find out what goes wrong.

Comment: @nvoigt Thank you so much!
In console now I can see "Expected a value of type 'int', but got one of type double".
I believe it's the cause. Could you tell me the best way to find the exact var causing the trouble? I've got about 300 lines of code from quicktype for converting json and have no idea how to find the exact var which destructs everything

Comment: There should be a stacktrace in the error with file and line number.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code. Here is the outcome

It came in is catch block line.Here you are emitting no value. So only Its still in loading state.

```
 Future<void> fetchWeatherApi() async {
    emit(WeatherFetchLoading());

    try {
      final Weather weather = await apiRepository.getWeather();
      print('hello');

      emit(WeatherFetchLoaded(weather: weather));
    } on Failure catch (err) {
      emit(WeatherFetchError(failure: err));
    } catch (err) {
      print("Error 1: $err");  **// Here** 
    }
  }
```

It shows

> 'double' is not a subtype of type 'int'

[image]

This is a parsing issue while converting to the values to double.
Your approach of parsing json is not a recommended way. You can [read here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json) more about json parsing.
If you need to continue to debug ,it may be time consuming to find exact field. You can try looking on each field . **You need to make sure you are parsing correct data type.** Model class and json should have same data type.

Comment: you've done my day and you're the best person in the world!